# What are the dimensions of the bolt that holds the front door check arm on the Megane 3?

Tags: renault, bolts, megane

I almost tore off the head of the screw holding the front door limiter on a Renault Megane 3. So I want to buy one for the case, if I have to drill it out. But I look at the websites of spare parts suppliers and I don't see it anywhere to identify its dimensions. The one in the photo is the other one, which is already back and glued, so I don't want to take it out again to measure it.

[image: Bolt]
[image: Head]

Comment: I highly suggest you just go to a breakers yard (junk/wrecking yard ... whatever you call it) and get some from there. My experience has been you can get several for very cheap. Something about buying new from someplace other than the dealership is, it's not going to be exactly the same.  Getting a used one from a wrecking yard will get you exactly what you need for a good price.

Comment: Thx, thats a great idea.